# Do databases use foreign keys transparently?

Tags: database, postgresql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, rdbms

Do database engines utilize foreign keys transparently or a query should explicitly use them?

Based on my experience there is no explicit notion of foreign keys on a table, except that a constraint that maintains uniqueness of the key and the fact that the key (single or a group of fields) is a key which makes search efficient.

To clarify this, here is an example why it is important: I have a middleware (in particular ArcGIS for my case), for which I can control the back-end database (so I can create keys, indices, etc.) and I usually use the front (a RESTful API here). The middleware itself is a black box and to provide effective tools to take advantage of the underlying DBMS's capabilities. So what I want to understand is that if I build foreign key constraints and use queries that if implemented normally would translate into queries that would use those foreign keys, should I see performance improvements?

Is that generally the case or various engines do it differently? (I am using PostgresSQL).

Comment: The only purpose of a foreign key is to enforce integrity. It is not "used" by a query.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys aren't there to improve performance. They're there to enforce data integrity. They will *decrease* performance for inserts/updates/deletes, but they make no difference to queries.

Some DBMSs will automatically add an index to the foreign key field, which may be where the confusion is coming from. Postgres does not do this; you'll need to create the index yourself. (And yes, the database will use this index transparently.)

Comment: Actually (some) DBMS *do* use foreign keys (or constraints in general) to improve performance. See here for an example: http://www.orafaq.com/node/2579 (I believe Postgres does have some optimizations like that as well)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Database engines needs specific queries to use foreign keys. You have to write some sort of join queries to get data from related tables.

However some Data access framework hides the complexity of accessing data from foreign keys by providing transparent way of accessing data from related tables but I am not sure that may provide much improvement in performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely depends on the database engine.

In PostgreSQL constraints won't cause performance improvements directly, only indexes will do that.

> [`CREATE INDEX`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html) is a PostgreSQL language extension. There are no provisions for indexes in the SQL standard.

However, adding *some* constraints will automatically create an index for that column(s) -- f.ex. `UNIQUE` & `PRIMARY KEY` constraints creates a `btree` index on the affected column(s).

The [`FOREIGN KEY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) constraint won't **create** indexes on the *referencing column(s)*, but:

> A foreign key must reference columns that either are a primary key or form a unique constraint. This means that the referenced columns always have an index (the one underlying the primary key or unique constraint); so checks on whether a referencing row has a match will be efficient. Since a DELETE of a row from the referenced table or an UPDATE of a referenced column will require a scan of the referencing table for rows matching the old value, it is often a good idea to index the referencing columns too. Because this is not always needed, and there are many choices available on how to index, declaration of a foreign key constraint does not automatically create an index on the referencing columns.